# Hot to find in dojo element when I know id of parent and I know type and style class of element which I looking fo

Tags: dojo

Hot to find in dojo element when I know id of parent and I know type and style class of element which I looking for ?
For example, I want find and change (span style=tabLabel) **ALARMS** into **Mga alarma**

```
<div dojoattachpoint="focusNode" role="tab" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="tab_div_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_1" tabindex="-1" title="" aria-selected="false">
                <img dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitIcon dijitTabButtonIcon dijitNoIcon" alt="" src="dojoroot/dojo/resources/blank.gif">
                <span class="tabLabel" dojoattachpoint="containerNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Alarms</span>
                <span role="presentation" dojoattachevent="onclick: onClickCloseButton" dojoattachpoint="closeNode" class="dijitInline dijitTabCloseButton dijitTabCloseIcon" style="display: none;">
                    <span class="dijitTabCloseText" dojoattachpoint="closeText">[x]</span></span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is pretty easy. If you look at the span element you refer to it has a dojoattachpoint attribute specified. That means that the node can be accessed from the widget directly with that name.

Now I assume that the widget is called "tab_div_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_1" from the id in your code so to get the widget:

```
var widget = dijit.byId("tab_div_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_1");
```

And the dojoattachpoint on the span has the value containerNode so:

```
widget.containerNode.innerHTML = "Mga alarma";
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a custom widget template and wish to localize a string, there is a mechanism to do this.  Simply use a substitution pattern like ${alarm} and define a javascript property on your widget with that name.  That property can then be populated with a localization bundle using dojo.i18n.  You can look at some of the dijits like [dijit.Dialog.postMixInProperties](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/tags/release-1.6.0/dijit/Dialog.js) to see how this is done.